# How to fixed Project Permission Denied problem for update draft grade and assigned grade of student submission

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-api-client, google-classroom

I want to update the draft grade and assigned grade from Google Classroom using API.

I can update draft grade and assigned grade using the environment of [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/patch?apix_params=%7B%22courseId%22%3A%22328776504166%22%2C%22courseWorkId%22%3A%22393728101130%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22Cg4IoeDCvNwJEIqWmOC6Cw%22%2C%22updateMask%22%3A%22draftGrade%2CassignedGrade%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22draftGrade%22%3A30%2C%22assignedGrade%22%3A100%7D%7D) cause I created a course manually where "associated with developer": true .

**Localhost Code:**

```
$client = getClient();
        $service = new Google_Service_Classroom($client);
        $courseId = '328776504166';
        $courseWorkId = '393728101130';
        $id = 'Cg4IoeDCvNwJEIqWmOC6Cw';
        $post_body = new Google_Service_Classroom_StudentSubmission(array(
            'assignedGrade' => 10,
            'draftGrade' => 90
        ));
        $params = array(
            'updateMask' => 'assignedGrade,draftGrade'
          );

        $list = $service->courses_courseWork_studentSubmissions->patch($courseId, $courseWorkId, $id, $post_body,$params);
```

But I can't update draft grade and assigned grade using localhost. PERMISSION_DENIED problem appear when I want to update the draft grade from localhost.

**Problem:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "@ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is not pe
rmitted to make this request.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "@ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is no
t permitted to make this request.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

**How to solve this problem?**

Comment: which api did you enable in google cloud console?

Comment: @DaImTo I have enabled Google Classroom API in google cloud console.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the option `"associated with developer": true`?

Comment: @Iamblichus I want to create course, coursework (assignments) and submit assign grade in Google Classroom. Then I want to this grade update from my application using Classroom API. Is it possible without create courses, coursework from my application?

Comment: I'm asking about the option `"associated with developer": true`. Where can you find this option?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation [Method: courses.courseWork.patch](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/patch)

> PERMISSION_DENIED if the requesting developer project did not create the corresponding course work, if the user is not permitted to make the requested modification to the student submission, or for [access errors](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Access.Errors).

Which then leads to.

> ProjectPermissionDenied indicates that the request attempted to modify a resource associated with a different Developer Console project.

Remember the try mean uses Googles console project not yours.   So if you created it with try me there is no way you will get permission to patch it without again using the try me.

You are mixing console projects.  Use yours to create it and use yours to patch it.

Comment: That means If I want to updates one or more fields of a student submission(  draft grade and assigned grade ) Is it I needed to create course work from my localhost project? If I create coursework from my Google Classroom or by Try this API Is it I can't update student submission?

Comment: It means that you should not be using the Try me for anything but testing.  It should not be part of your production application.